# jQuery AJAX request results in error with no message

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, rest

I am new to both jQuery and AJAX, and I'm trying to retrieve data from a REST service. The service I'm trying to use can be found here: http://www.groupkt.com/post/c9b0ccb9/country-and-other-related-rest-webservices.htm (Specifically the fourth topic).

A snippet of my code is below.

```
var displayResources = $('#display-resources');
var iso2code = $('#country').val();

displayResources.text('Loading data from JSON source...');
/* AJAX Call to RESTful Service */
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://services.groupkt.com/country/search?' ,
  data: {'text': iso2code},
  success: function(result)
```

This request always returns an error status with a blank message. I've tried messing with the type, url, and adding a dataType, but nothing I do changes the outcome. I figure I must be going about this wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Gotta give us more information.  What response code does it get?  What error message does it get?  Do you see any mesages in your console?

Comment: That API is not CORS enabled. You will need to use a server side proxy either on your server or a third party service

Comment: Try removing the question mark from the end of the url.

Comment: I see in the console that there was a CORS issue, as charlietfl said. I tried changing the datatype to jsonp snd it gives me code 200, though still triggers the error event.

Comment: The API has to serve jsonp....most don't. You would need to check docs